# Why compilers test the least significant bit in an address?

Tags: c++

Consider this function in https://github.com/coolwanglu/PDFium.js/blob/master/core/src/fpdfapi/fpdf_page/fpdf_page_parser.cpp:

```
FX_BOOL CPDF_StreamContentParser::OnOperator(FX_LPCSTR op)
{
    int i = 0;
    FX_DWORD opid = 0;
    while (i < 4 && op[i]) {
        opid = (opid << 8) + op[i];
        i ++;
    }
    while (i < 4) {
        opid <<= 8;
        i ++;
    };
    int low = 0, high = sizeof g_OpCodes / sizeof(struct _OpCode) - 1;
    while (low <= high) {
        int middle = (low + high) / 2;
        int compare = opid - g_OpCodes[middle].m_OpId;
        if (compare == 0) {
            (this->*g_OpCodes[middle].m_OpHandler)();
            return TRUE;
        } else if (compare < 0) {
            high = middle - 1;
        } else {
            low = middle + 1;
        }
    }
    return m_CompatCount != 0;
}
```

This function is used in FoxitReader 2.4 and it is compiled as:

```
Dump of assembler code for function _ZN24CPDF_StreamContentParser10OnOperatorEPKc:
   0x0000000000bc71fe <+0>: xor    edx,edx
   0x0000000000bc7200 <+2>: xor    eax,eax
   0x0000000000bc7202 <+4>: movsx  r8d,BYTE PTR [rsi+rdx*1]
   0x0000000000bc7207 <+9>: mov    ecx,edx
   0x0000000000bc7209 <+11>:    test   r8b,r8b
   0x0000000000bc720c <+14>:    je     0xbc7222 <_ZN24CPDF_StreamContentParser10OnOperatorEPKc+36>
   0x0000000000bc720e <+16>:    shl    eax,0x8
   0x0000000000bc7211 <+19>:    inc    rdx
   0x0000000000bc7214 <+22>:    add    eax,r8d
   0x0000000000bc7217 <+25>:    cmp    rdx,0x4
   0x0000000000bc721b <+29>:    jne    0xbc7202 <_ZN24CPDF_StreamContentParser10OnOperatorEPKc+4>
   0x0000000000bc721d <+31>:    mov    ecx,0x4
   0x0000000000bc7222 <+36>:    cmp    ecx,0x4
   0x0000000000bc7225 <+39>:    je     0xbc722e <_ZN24CPDF_StreamContentParser10OnOperatorEPKc+48>
   0x0000000000bc7227 <+41>:    shl    eax,0x8
   0x0000000000bc722a <+44>:    inc    ecx
   0x0000000000bc722c <+46>:    jmp    0xbc7222 <_ZN24CPDF_StreamContentParser10OnOperatorEPKc+36>
   0x0000000000bc722e <+48>:    lea    r10,[rip+0x180f43b]        # 0x23d6670 <_ZL9g_OpCodes>
   0x0000000000bc7235 <+55>:    mov    cl,0x48
   0x0000000000bc7237 <+57>:    xor    esi,esi
   0x0000000000bc7239 <+59>:    lea    edx,[rsi+rcx*1]
   0x0000000000bc723c <+62>:    sar    edx,1
   0x0000000000bc723e <+64>:    movsxd r9,edx
   0x0000000000bc7241 <+67>:    imul   r8,r9,0x18
   0x0000000000bc7245 <+71>:    add    r8,r10
   0x0000000000bc7248 <+74>:    cmp    eax,DWORD PTR [r8]
   0x0000000000bc724b <+77>:    jne    0xbc727c <_ZN24CPDF_StreamContentParser10OnOperatorEPKc+126>
   0x0000000000bc724d <+79>:    push   rcx
   0x0000000000bc724e <+80>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [r8+0x8]
   0x0000000000bc7252 <+84>:    test   al,0x1
   0x0000000000bc7254 <+86>:    je     0xbc7263 <_ZN24CPDF_StreamContentParser10OnOperatorEPKc+101>
   0x0000000000bc7256 <+88>:    mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [r8+0x10]
   0x0000000000bc725a <+92>:    mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rdi+rdx*1]
   0x0000000000bc725e <+96>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rdx+rax*1-0x1]
   0x0000000000bc7263 <+101>:   imul   r9,r9,0x18
   0x0000000000bc7267 <+105>:   lea    rdx,[rip+0x180f402]        # 0x23d6670 <_ZL9g_OpCodes>
   0x0000000000bc726e <+112>:   add    rdi,QWORD PTR [rdx+r9*1+0x10]
   0x0000000000bc7273 <+117>:   call   rax
   0x0000000000bc7275 <+119>:   mov    eax,0x1
   0x0000000000bc727a <+124>:   pop    rdx
   0x0000000000bc727b <+125>:   ret    
   0x0000000000bc727c <+126>:   jns    0xbc7283 <_ZN24CPDF_StreamContentParser10OnOperatorEPKc+133>
   0x0000000000bc727e <+128>:   lea    ecx,[rdx-0x1]
   0x0000000000bc7281 <+131>:   jmp    0xbc7286 <_ZN24CPDF_StreamContentParser10OnOperatorEPKc+136>
   0x0000000000bc7283 <+133>:   lea    esi,[rdx+0x1]
   0x0000000000bc7286 <+136>:   cmp    esi,ecx
   0x0000000000bc7288 <+138>:   jle    0xbc7239 <_ZN24CPDF_StreamContentParser10OnOperatorEPKc+59>
   0x0000000000bc728a <+140>:   xor    eax,eax
   0x0000000000bc728c <+142>:   cmp    DWORD PTR [rdi+0x454],0x0
   0x0000000000bc7293 <+149>:   setne  al
   0x0000000000bc7296 <+152>:   ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

Please note instructions +84 through +96 which corresponds to `(this->*g_OpCodes[middle].m_OpHandler)();`. The register rax holds the pointer to the handler function, but instead of calling it directly the compiler adds those instructions and test for the least significant bit, why?

I found other instances of this in other functions. Like in the function void CFX_Renderer::render(const Scanline& sl) in 
https://github.com/priority5/qt/blob/2a6b2348ced4cb42e8e3c320a6e5aa3606c0d5a1/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/pdfium/core/fxge/agg/fx_agg_driver.cpp :

```
 (this->*composite_span)(..args..);
```

which corresponds to:

```
   0x0000000000c40a6c <+480>:   test   dl,0x1
   0x0000000000c40a6f <+483>:   mov    rax,rdx
   0x0000000000c40a72 <+486>:   je     0xc40a7d <_ZN12CFX_Renderer6renderIN5fxagg10scanline_uIhEEEEvRKT_+497>
   0x0000000000c40a74 <+488>:   mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbx+rdi*1]
   0x0000000000c40a78 <+492>:   mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rdx+rax*1-0x1]
   0x0000000000c40a7d <+497>:   mov    edx,DWORD PTR [r15+0x4]
```

Comment: Most things, like functions and (most) variables are alligned on some size that's not a multiple of a single byte. so the last bit will never be anything but zero.

Comment: Obvious question - which compiler?

Comment: @NeilButterworth I dont know .. I downloaded the compiled binary from https://www.foxitsoftware.com/downloads/

Comment: @JesperJuhl I see your point, but still I dont see why the check in first place ..

Comment: Multiple inheritance shenanigans, most likely.  Matters a lot for member function pointers that *might* reference an object of a class that uses virtual inheritance.  Googling "v-table thunks" for the compiler you use could well pay off.

Comment: x86_64 calling convention, `rdi` holds the first argument passed to the function, so whatever is passed is being tested odd/even for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last value is used for specifying whether the function pointer is virtual or not.

If the LSB of a function pointer is 1, it means that the function is virtual, so a binary should use the virtual function table to call this function. Otherwise, the binary uses the function pointer as a function address.

You can see this behavior from the following code (mostly from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/virtual-function-cpp/).

```cpp
// CPP program to illustrate
// concept of Virtual Functions
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class base
{
public:
    virtual void print ()
    { cout<< "print base class" <<endl; }

    virtual void wow ()
    { cout<< "print base class" <<endl; }

    void show ()
    { cout<< "show base class" <<endl; }
};

class derived:public base
{
public:
    void print ()
    { cout<< "print derived class" <<endl; }

    void show ()
    { cout<< "show derived class" <<endl; }
};

int main()
{
    base *bptr;
    derived d;
    bptr = &d;

    //virtual function, binded at runtime
    printf("%p\n", &derived::print);

    //virtual function, binded at runtime
    printf("%p\n", &derived::wow);

    // Non-virtual function, binded at compile time
    printf("%p\n", &derived::show);
}
```

If you run this program, you will get

```sh
$ ./run
0x1
0x9
0x5594923dac92
```

This shows that pointers for virtual functions are actually offsets with LSB 1,
and the non-virtual function's pointer is the function address itself.

Answer (score 4):

I am guessing that the compiler uses odd addresses to indicate funky function pointers, perhaps indicating indirection through the class vtable, or some other mapping, perhaps for dynamic loaded code, where r8 is the class pointer?

My best guess is this is a pointer to member function, and that could either be a simple member function, or a virtual function. If it is simple it is the raw address and if it is virtual it is the funky pointer value.

If the "pointer" is even, then it is used directly, if it is odd it plings through r8 (probably the object instance) and rdi, and I have no idea what is in rdi, before applying rax as an offset with the 1 subtracted. It will depend heavily on the calling conventions of the platform and whatever tricks the compiler is playing.

```
0x0000000000bc724e <+80>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [r8+0x8]
0x0000000000bc7252 <+84>:    test   al,0x1
0x0000000000bc7254 <+86>:    je     0xbc7263 <_ZN24CPDF_StreamContentParser10OnOperatorEPKc+101>
0x0000000000bc7256 <+88>:    mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [r8+0x10]
0x0000000000bc725a <+92>:    mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rdi+rdx*1]
0x0000000000bc725e <+96>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rdx+rax*1-0x1]
0x0000000000bc7263 <+101>:   imul   r9,r9,0x18
0x0000000000bc7267 <+105>:   lea    rdx,[rip+0x180f402]        # 0x23d6670 <_ZL9g_OpCodes>
0x0000000000bc726e <+112>:   add    rdi,QWORD PTR [rdx+r9*1+0x10]
0x0000000000bc7273 <+117>:   call   rax
```